# Change the Control of CAML XML fragment

Tags: infopath, forms-services, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections, document-info-panel

- I am able to update the Infopath Form to SharePoint List by following the [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc162745(v=office.12).aspx),But it is
  accepting only text box control values
- Below are the fields which are in CAML XML fragment format,And I am
  unable to change the fields from text box to dropdown

Can any one help me in changing the control

```
<Batch OnError="Continue">
    <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
        <Field Name='HRNAME'></Field>
        <Field Name="FirstName"></Field>
        <Field Name="LastName"></Field>
        <Field Name="Phone"></Field>
        <Field Name="Email"></Field>
        <Field Name="ID"></Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

Comment: I'm confused by this question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please view the below link
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a7672234-d07c-4a84-920f-10037b6da844/update-the-sharepoint-list-using-infopath-forms?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: What part of this "how to" are you having issues with?